# Second row of headers in table

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I have a table that I'm building dynamically using a datatable. I'm using

```
<f:facet name="header">
```

to handle the header row, but now, I need a second header row to add more information.

I tried adding a second f:facet but what this did was put a header per line and, of course, messed up the table.

This is what I need it to look like:

[image]

The second header row being the "USER COMPUTER UNMANAGED" row.

Any ideas?

Comment: Build your own `<table>` component and fill it using `<ui:repeat>` instead of `<h:dataTable>`. Otherwise, rely on third party libraries like PrimeFaces which lets you use `<p:cell>` to achieve the desired look n' feel. Some examples: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableHeaderFooter.jsf and http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableGrouping.jsf

Comment: That did it! Feel free to leave it as an answer so I can mark it as correct.

Comment: It would be better if you post an answer showing the JSF code that solved the problem.